# TextBox hidden underneath Bitmap

Tags: flash

I'm working in Flash Professional CS6. I have a bitmap image that is a wooden box. I want to have two text boxes on top of this bitmap image, however when I move the text boxes on top of the image they are hidden underneath. Any text in the text boxes does not show up since the image is covering them.

How do I make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out. If you right click and go to arrange there is a "send to back" option.

Comment: Hmm. While this makes it appear correct in CS6, while running in flash the text is still invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try separating out the text fields on to their own layer and put that above the layer containing the bitmap (this is assuming you have no code).

If you do have (AS3) code, try looking for an addChild() call that might be moving the bitmap above the text fields in the display stack. Also calling addChild() and passing in the text fields will move them up to the top of the display stack (even if they were already on the display stack).

Answer (score 0):

I believe if send to back doesn't help you, then the problem is perhaps not what you think.

- Try changing the font of the text box (say to Arial) & color.
- Often not embedding the font, causes the text box to be rendered
  blank (if not available at run time)
- Besides try and wrap up objects into symbols before putting them on
  stage.
- And if you are using the IDE, you might as well make use of layering.